# Playa + Pagination = nothing… Why?

Tags: playa, pagination

I guess I'm missing something obvious since I haven't found any question on this subject… I'm trying to paginate results from `exp:playa:parents` tags to no avail… That's what I got:

```
{exp:playa:parents parent_id="{low_events:entry_ids}" disable="categories|category_fields" limit="5" paginate="bottom"}
  HTML…
  {paginate}
    {pagination_links}
    <ul>
      {page}
      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="{if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
      {/page}
    </ul>
    {/pagination_links}
  {/paginate}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

From the Playa docs, it sounds like I'm supposed to override `disable="pagination"` which i set to `true` by default. That's what I'm going for with `disable="categories|category_fields"` and that's the only thing I can think of that might be the problem… (I don't actually know if that's how you're supposed to override the default).

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Your override is correct for `disable`. What output do you get? Do you see the `{pagination}` tags unprocessed, or do they parse yet are empty? Maybe a stupid question: do you have more than 5 entries in the `{low_events:entry_ids}` field? What happens if you manually append `/P5` to the URL?

Comment: I've actually changed the limit to 1 for testing anyway (and I got more than 1 entry ;) It doesn't output anything (which means the pagination tags are parsed I guess). Manually changing the URL doesn't change the output… Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Are you by chance using either Structure or Freebie?

Comment: Nope. I'm using a few add-ons but nothing unusual… The only one I've never used before that might have something to do with it is low_events but as far as I can tell, it's only outputting a list of IDs for Playa to work with. Maybe I'll code up a jQuery pagination instead… Bummer though. Thanks for trying to sort it out! It's always good to get a second pair of eyes on a problem :)

Comment: Im having this same issue. It outputs the pagination links, which bring you to the correct url (P25 for example), but the results on the page dont change.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you already have a anwser yet. But I had the same problem and I. I want to enable pagination within a Playa loop.

You need to do 2 things to enable pagination in a Playa loop.

- Override the default disable of “categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination”.
- Put var_prefix in your Playa tag and pagination tag.

You did a good override of the default disables with `disable="categories|category_fields"`  but also `disable=""` will work if you want to enable all this.

So you only have to do a prefix in your loop and your code should look something like this:

```
{exp:playa:parents parent_id="{low_events:entry_ids}" disable="categories|category_fields" limit="5" paginate="bottom" var_prefix="your_prefix"}
  HTML…
  {your_prefix:paginate}
    {pagination_links}
    <ul>
      {page}
      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="{if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
      {/page}
    </ul>
    {/pagination_links}
  {/your_prefix:paginate}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I ended up going another route so I can't verify if your solution works in this particular case, but I will definitely try it out when I have time. Where did you find info on `var_prefix` ? I find the docs to be really lacking since they updated their site. Thanks again!

Comment: Thats a good question. It cost me a few days to find the right solution. I read somewhere(don't ask me where, i don't remeber) if you want to use pagination in a Playa loop you need to use `var_prefix`. I did that and it still didn't work. The [Playa docs](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/parents.html) chapter var_prefix explains you need to enable pagination. But I didn't know how to do this. Then I come across your question. You explained to me how I need to enable pagination. I combined me knowledge with yours and there it was :). So thanks to you to!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried following the instructions here: https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/pagination_in_playa#reply_6602199 ?

Comment: broken link :'(

Comment: Yeah, GetSat killed it a month or so ago :( Meanwhile, it was a similar approach that Nielex suggested above, only not using var_prefix but an embed. His way is smarter, by the way :)