# I'm having trouble getting simple IF statements within a Playa tag to evaluate properly

Tags: playa, variable, ifelse

**Channels and Fields Summary**:

- `Tours` channel - stores a list of all Vacations the site offers
- - `tour_specials` field - a Playa field, linked to the `Specials` channel indicating which Special Offers apply to this tour
- - `tour_show_specials_banner` field - a Switch to determine whether to show a special offer banner against this entry, if the `tour_specials` field has any entries
- `Specials` channel - list of Special Offers that can apply to multiple tours
- `Promotions` channel - stores lists of tours our partners want to promote. Though it sounds similar to Specials, it is distinct from a business perspective.
- - `promotion_tours` field - a Playa field that stores multiple `tours` channel entries, indicating which tours are linked to a promotion

**The Problem**:

- I have created a Promotions page that gets a Promotion, and lists all `tours` associated with the promotion from the `promotion_tours` Playa field
- The listing of tours in the Promotion also needs to check whether a tour has a Special Offer running, by looking at the `tour_specials` field in the `tours` entry to see if any `Specials` apply
- However, all the various code blocks below **WILL NOT** ever evaluate to true, in the event a tour listed has a Special associated with it

**The Code**:

Here's the master code block that outputs all Playa entries from the `promotion_tours` field (all tours associated with the promotion):

```
{promotion_tours dynamic_parameters="orderby|sort|limit" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="10" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data" var_prefix="promotions" paginate="bottom"}

    <a href="{promotions:site_url}/{promotions:url_title}">
        <img src="{promotions:tour_gallery limit="1"}{promotions:tour_photo_file:thumbnail}{/promotions:tour_gallery}"/>

        <!-- PROBLEM STARTS HERE -->
        <!-- If we want to show a Special Offer banner... -->
        {if promotions:tour_show_specials_banner}

            <!-- Then check if there are any linked Specials -->
            {if {promotions:tour_specials:total_children} > 0}
                    <img class="special-offer-banner" src="{site_url}images/site/special-offer.png" alt="Special Offer" title="Special Offer" />
            {/if}

        {/if}
    </a>

{/promotion_tours}
```

I am using a `var_prefix` to allow my Playa entries to be paginated ([see here for an explanation](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14723/playa-pagination-nothing-why)).

You can see where the problem starts is with `{if promotions:tour_show_specials_banner}`. That statement NEVER evaluates as TRUE, even when I know it should do. The following situations NEVER output anything:

```
{if promotions:tour_show_specials_banner}
{if tour_show_specials_banner}
{if {promotions:tour_show_specials_banner} == "y"}
{if promotions:tour_show_specials_banner == "y"}
{if {tour_show_specials_banner} == "y"}
```

I know some are syntactically incorrect but I'm getting to my wits end here...

HOWEVER, if I just output `{promotions:tour_show_specials_banner}` in my HTML, it outputs `y` in to the content! Which must evaluate as `TRUE`!

I'm seriously stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues in EE 2.9 with conditionals on prefixed variables and variable modifiers which I don't totally grok. ([See bug report here for some discussion.](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20621/variables-with-modifiers-not-working-in-conditionals-without-braces))

But the moral is, try this:

```
{if '{promotions:tour_show_specials_banner}' == 'y'}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much Derek. I had been tearing my hair out over this.  Really appreciate the response, thank you!